# Can't start topshelf service locally: The service did not respond in a timely fashion

Tags: c#, windows-10, topshelf

I am having difficulties to start my service using the following setup.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule<FixAcceptorModule>();
    var container = builder.Build();

    var rc = HostFactory.Run(c =>
    {
        c.UseAutofacContainer(container);
        c.Service<IServiceManager>(svc =>
        {
            svc.ConstructUsingAutofacContainer();
            svc.WhenStarted(sm => sm.Start()).BeforeStartingService(a => a.RequestAdditionalTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
            svc.WhenStopped(sm => sm.Stop());
        });

        c.SetDescription("");
        c.SetDisplayName("FIX Acceptor Service");
        c.SetServiceName("FixAcceptorSvc");

        c.RunAsLocalService();
        c.StartManually();
    });
}
```

This is the output of the start action `myservice.exe start`:

```
Topshelf.Hosts.StartHost Error: 0 : The service failed to start., System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service FixAcceptorSvc on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start()
   at Topshelf.Runtime.Windows.WindowsHostEnvironment.StartService(String serviceName, TimeSpan startTimeOut)
   at Topshelf.Hosts.StartHost.Run()
```

Although the exception points to a timeout I don't think this is related to a timing issue, as this exception get's thrown immediately. I guess it's more like a permission or configuration issue.

**Things to note:**

- My developer machine is a domain joined and runs `Windows 10 Pro - 1909`
- When starting the service from Visual Studio 2019 in Debug configuration everything works perfectly
- `myservice.exe install --localservice` (and `c.RunAsLocalSystem()` in `HostFactory`) => same result
- `myservice.exe install --localsystem` (and `c.RunAsLocalSystem()` in `HostFactory`) => same result
- Also using `myservice.exe install -username myaduser -password myadpassword` did not help (double checked group policies and that my user is allowed to logon as a service)

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens when you debug it? Is `Start()` or `Stop()` method reached?

Comment: Thx for replying. The thing was that it works without an issue when debugging. My problem was related to the path where related configuration files where searched for

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned exception is totally misleading. I found the culprit. To get more details I've added the following action:

```
c.OnException(ex =>
{
    File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Temp\Service.txt", ex.ToString());
});
```

Now this finally got me on the track. As the exception shows there is something wrong with my service, which is looking in the wrong folder (`C:\Windows\System32`) for the FIX dictionary... Problem solved!

```
Topshelf.ServiceBuilderException: An exception occurred creating the service: IServiceManager ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating StrukiApp.FixAcceptor.Infrastructure.ServiceManager -> StrukiApp.FixAcceptor.Acceptor. ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(QuickFix.IApplication, QuickFix.IMessageStoreFactory, QuickFix.SessionSettings, QuickFix.ILogFactory)' on type 'Acceptor'. ---> QuickFix.ConfigError: Configuration failed: Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\FIX44.xml'. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\FIX44.xml'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at QuickFix.SessionFactory.createDataDictionary(SessionID sessionID, Dictionary settings, String settingsKey, String beginString)
   at QuickFix.SessionFactory.ProcessFixDataDictionary(SessionID sessionID, Dictionary settings, DataDictionaryProvider provider)
   at QuickFix.SessionFactory.Create(SessionID sessionID, Dictionary settings)
   at QuickFix.ThreadedSocketAcceptor.CreateSession(SessionID sessionID, Dictionary dict)
   at QuickFix.ThreadedSocketAcceptor.CreateSessions(SessionSettings settings, SessionFactory sessionFactory)
   at QuickFix.ThreadedSocketAcceptor..ctor(SessionFactory sessionFactory, SessionSettings settings)
```

Comment: I get an error saying that 'HostConfigurator' does not contain a definition for 'OnException'...  Please let me know how you were able to add that to your code.